# Solve for element of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say we have a system of equations

$$\mathbf{xA}=\mathbf{y}$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are both $1\times n$. Say we wanted to write an expression for element $a_{ij}$ of this matrix. Is this possible?

Comment: What else do you know about $A$?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very much underdetermined.  Look at some simple examples, say $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \end{bmatrix}$: The only information you have on $a$ is that $x_1 a + x_2 b = y_1$: If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are nonzero then this has infinitely many solutions for $a$, as you can choose $a$ freely and adjust by choice of $b$.